# Problem connecting to web services from MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Online Non-US instances

Tags: wcf, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Connecting to outside Web Services from Dynamics CRM 2011 online works from a US instance, however the exact same code does not work from an instance in the Singapore (Data centre for Australia where my clients and our company are located):

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://my.domain.com/webservice");
DataService1 client = new DataService1(binding, address);
client.RunMethod();
```

On a non-US instance this code returns the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]:
System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error.
Reference number for administrators or support: #2BEE9520
```

Has anyone been able to do anything similar from a non US instance of CRM2011 Online?

Comment: Link to other example of problem: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/41c0e19b-ada9-42ce-8ca9-dd83538a356e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was corrected a couple of months ago as referenced by this forum thread: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/41c0e19b-ada9-42ce-8ca9-dd83538a356e/

I have now successfully tested this myself and found it to be true.

Answer (score 0):

The code example here should solve your issue.
http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crmgirishraja/archive/2011/03/22/crm-online-2011-web-services-soap-sample-now-ready-for-europe-amp-asia.aspx

Comment: The problem is not accessing the CRM web serivce, but access to external web services from within a CRM Plugin. This works fine in Sandbox mode on premise and from the US data centre, just not the Asia data centre